# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to method.__format__

Tags: python

I am getting an error message as follows:  TypeError: unsupported format string passed to method.__format __.

I am using a Linux environment and this code should calculate interest rates.There are seperate files for running the scripts and the function.However once entering the data in the page, i am directed to an error message at the page stating that the format is incorrect before the following code:

```
return render_template('interest_form.html', totale="{0:.2f}".format(totale))
```

Below is the full code:

```
from server import app, valid_time
from flask import request, render_template
from Calculator import Calculator


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def interest_total():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        initial=float(request.form["initial"])
        rate=float(request.form["rate"])
        time=float(request.form["time"])
        data=Calculator(initial,rate)
        data.total_interest(time)
        totale=data.total_interest
        return render_template('interest_form.html', totale="{0:.2f}".format(totale))
    return render_template('interest_form.html', calc_total=True)


@app.route('/time', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def time_interest():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        initial=float(request.form["initial"])
        rate=float(request.form["rate"])
        total=float(request.form["total"])
        dataa=Calculator(initial,rate)
        dataa.time_required(total)
        time=dataa.time_required
        return render_template('interest_form.html', time="{0:.2f}".format(time))
    return render_template('interest_form.html', calc_time=True)



@app.route('/credits', methods=['GET'])
def credits():
return render_template('credits.html')
```

This is the code for the Calculator part:

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, initial, rate):

        """
        Pass in the initial amount invested
        and the rate as a percentage (ie 50 for 50%)
        """
        self._initial = initial
        self._rate = rate/100

    def total_interest(self, time):
        """
        Returns the total amoun of interest after a given length of time
        """
        return self._initial * self._rate * time

    def time_required(self, total):
        """
        Returns the length of time required to achieve a given total
        """
        return total/(self._initial * self._rate)
```

I am trying using a html form to send the input:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<html>
<body>
<div>
    <form action="" method='POST'>
         <div style="margin: 10px 0px">
            <label>Amount Invested ($): </label><br/>
            <input  name="initial" input type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Amount Invested"/>
        </div>
         <div style="margin: 10px 0px">
            <label>Interest Rate (%): </label><br/>
            <input  name="rate" input type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Amount Invested"/>
        </div>
         <div style="margin: 10px 0px">
            <label>Time Investment (Years): </label><br/>
            <input name="time" input type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Amount Invested"  {%if calc_time %}disabled{% endif %}/>
        </div>
         <div style="margin: 10px 0px">
            <label>Total Interest ($): </label><br/>
            <input  name="total" input type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Amount Invested"  {%if calc_total %}disabled{% endif %}/>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 10px 0px">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>

                {% if totale %}<h4>Total amount is</h4>
                <textarea name="Amount" rows="5" cols="20"> {{totale}}</textarea>
                {% endif %}
                </form>
        {% if time %}<h4>Total amount is</h4>
                <textarea name="Amount" rows="5" cols="20"> {{time}}</textarea>
                {% endif %}
                </form>
</div>
<div>
<a href="{{url_for('time_interest')}}">Time_Form</a>
<a href="{{url_for('interest_total')}}">Total Form</a>
<br/><a href="{{url_for('credits')}}">Credits Page</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

I have used a different template code that has a similar function and return format and when running it there seems to be no problem with it.This,however,seems to be showing the abovementioned error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set value `totale` by call the method, write

```
totale=data.total_interest(time)
#                         ^^^^^^
```

instead of

```
data.total_interest(time)
totale=data.total_interest
```

and the same in second case

```
time = dataa.time_required(total)
```

instead of

```
dataa.time_required(total)
time=dataa.time_require
```

In your definition, when you call the method you get a value, when you access to the method you get the description, for example:

```
In [14]: data.total_interest(time)
Out[14]: 2.8000000000000003
```

and

```
In [15]: data.total_interest
Out[15]: <bound method Calculator.total_interest of <__main__.Calculator object at 0x7f3e4c575668>>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!!Wasted about 4hrs trying to figure out the source of issue.Guess am still a beginner.If i may ask what is the difference in the two lines?

Comment: glad to help you